# How can I set the database to flag a message has been read?

Tags: php, mysql

here is my "read messages" code...

I want to add a code to know that the messages has been read or not...

```
<?php
session_start();
$userfinal=$_SESSION['sessioname'];
require "config.php";

$messageid = $_GET['messageid'];
$message = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id = '$messageid' AND to_user = '$userfinal'");
$message=mysql_fetch_assoc($message);

echo "<h1>Title: ".$message['message_title']."</h1><br><br>";
echo "<h3>From: ".$message['from_user']."<br><br></h3>";
echo "<h3>Message: <br>".$message['message_contents']."<br></h3>";

echo '<form name="backfrm" method="post" action="inbox.php">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Back to Inbox">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Just on this page somewhere add the update query to change the `read` flag to `1` provided you have the field `read` in your `message` table.

Comment: Add flag bool (read) to your messages table and check something like that:

   if (isset($messageid)) { // update flag to 1 };

Comment: Please include the code you've attempted (to keep track of "read" status) and what went wrong.

Comment: what is the code and where I put it?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: You should understand what you are doing before starting "programing". There are a lot of guides how to write PHP code and work with databases. Use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the user gets to this page, they have read this email. So just add an update of the messages tabele to this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$userfinal=$_SESSION['sessioname'];
require "config.php";

$messageid = $_GET['messageid'];
$message = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id = '$messageid' AND to_user = '$userfinal'");
$message=mysql_fetch_assoc($message);

// set message as read
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE messages SET `has_been_read` = 1 WHERE message_id = '$messageid'");
if ( !$result ) {
    // error updating the message to has_been_read
    // This bit is up to you!!!
}


echo "<h1>Title: ".$message['message_title']."</h1><br><br>";
echo "<h3>From: ".$message['from_user']."<br><br></h3>";
echo "<h3>Message: <br>".$message['message_contents']."<br></h3>";

echo '<form name="backfrm" method="post" action="inbox.php">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Back to Inbox">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: You are going to get nagged about using the deprecated mysql_* extension and not the new PDO or mysqli ones, and rightly so. But guys, little steps eh!